# Как получить все значения, свойства ... HTML элемента

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли к примеру в таком HTML-коде:

```html
<form method="post" action="https://passport.ru/auth?origin=">
  <input type="hidden" name="retpath" value="https://passport.ru/" wfd-invisible="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="fretpath" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="clean" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
  <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper">
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
      <button data-t="button:default" data-type="login" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_default" autocomplete="off">
             <span class="Button2-Text">Почта</span>
                </button></div>
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type"><button data- t="button:clear" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off"><span class="Button2-Text">Телефон</span>
           </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

То есть я нахожу и получаю элемент - form method="post":

```
{  
let elem = document.querySelector('[method="post"]');  
console.log(elem);
}
```

И вот возможно ли теперь по этому полученному элементу - получить/перебрать все значения, которые в нем будут: action, type, name, value, имена вложенных классов, data-type, type итд...

Comment: Через цикл имеете ввиду или просто иметь доступ к каждому аттрибуту?

Comment: можно конечно, почему нельзя..

Comment: @EzioMercer, наверное через цикл, то есть заранее кол-во и имя атрибута мне не известно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('[method="post"]');

const excludeProps = new Set(["textContent", "innerText", "outerText", "innerHTML", "outerHTML"])
const excludeAttrs = new Set(["for", "class"])
const empty = document.createElement(elem.tagName)

for (var prop in elem) {
  if (elem[prop] !== empty[prop] && typeof elem[prop] !== "function" && typeof elem[prop] !== "object" && !excludeProps.has(prop)) {
    console.log("prop", prop, elem[prop])
  }
}

for (var key in elem.dataset) {
  console.log("data", key, elem.dataset[prop])
}

for (var attr of elem.getAttributeNames()) {
  if (!(attr in elem) && !excludeAttrs.has(attr) && !attr.match(/^data-/i)) {
     console.log("attr", attr, elem.getAttribute(attr))
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://passport.ru/auth?origin=" data-x="10" data-smth-else="20" x-smth="qqq">
  <input type="hidden" name="retpath" value="https://passport.ru/" wfd-invisible="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="fretpath" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="clean" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
  <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper">
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
      <button data-t="button:default" data-type="login" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_default" autocomplete="off">
             <span class="Button2-Text">Почта</span>
                </button></div>
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type"><button data- t="button:clear" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off"><span class="Button2-Text">Телефон</span>
           </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Да что с вами не так сегодня?) Я обычно смотрю твои и Алексея ответы, чтобы посмотреть на короткие решения а тут вы стали громоздить))

Comment: @EzioMercer, зато моё работает правильнее. Доставать свойства через атрибуты плохо и не всегда правильно.

Comment: @EzioMercer, по формулировке вопроса вообще непонятно, чего нужно автору. Лишние свойства можно закинуть в `excludeProps` и тогда их не будет. По дефаултным значениям я уже сам подправил, чтобы не выводились. Что касается свойств и атрибутов - не уверен, что можно что-то с несоответствующими значениями повесить на форму, а чекбоксу сделать рассогласованный checked [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712017/4928642).

Comment: @EzioMercer, кстати, вот тут ещё про атрибуты [рассказывал](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mdk3ekWPGXk&t=1241s).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138223/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-eziomercer).

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто обратиться к свойству `attributes` у элемента:

```js
const querySelector = document.querySelector('#querySelector');

querySelector.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.code !== 'Enter') return;
  
  console.clear();
  
  const el = document.querySelector(e.target.value);

  for (const attr of el.attributes)
    console.log(attr.nodeName, attr.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="querySelector" type="text" placeholder="query selector" value="form"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<form method="post" action="https://passport.ru/auth?origin=">
  <input type=" hidden " name="retpath " value="https://passport.ru/ " wfd-invisible="true ">
  <input type="hidden " name="fretpath " value=" " wfd-invisible="true ">
  <input type="hidden " name="clean " value=" " wfd-invisible="true ">
  <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper ">
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type ">
      <button data-t="button:default " data-type="login " type="button " class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_default " autocomplete="off ">
             <span class="Button2-Text ">Почта</span>
                </button></div>
    <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type "><button data- t="button:clear " data-type="phone " type="button " class="Button2 Button2_size_l Button2_view_clear " autocomplete="off "><span class="Button2-Text ">Телефон</span>
           </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: А на input-ах и div-ах - не будет работать ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom Почему не будет? Будет, я добавил инпут, куда можете написать правильный селектор и потом нажать на `Enter` и он вам покажет все аттрибуты элемента

Answer (score 0):

```js
let element = document.querySelector('[method="post"]');

for (const [key, attribute] of Object.entries(element.attributes)) {
  console.log(`name: ${attribute.name},  value: ${attribute.value}`);
}
```

```html
 <form method="post" action="https://passport.ru/auth?origin">
      <input type="hidden" name="retpath" value="https://passport.ru/" wfd-invisible="true">
      <input type="hidden" name="fretpath" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
      <input type="hidden" name="clean" value="" wfd-invisible="true">
        <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-wrapper">
        <div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type">
          <button data-t="button:default" data-type="login" type="button" class="Button2 
          Button2_size_l Button2_view_default" autocomplete="off">
             <span class="Button2-Text">Почта</span>
                </button></div><div class="AuthLoginInputToggle-type"><button data- 
                t="button:clear" data-type="phone" type="button" class="Button2 Button2_size_l 
                Button2_view_clear" autocomplete="off"><span class="Button2-Text">Телефон</span>
           </button>
       </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Чё-то ты сложным путём пошёл, кажется :)